# Symfony2 template configuration from routing.yml

Tags: symfony

When dealing with the Sylius e-commerce bundles I have found what seems to be a way of configurig the template for a route, that I didn't know:

I have tested in a fresh Symfony RC 2.2.0 with vendors installation.
This would be in the routing.yml

```
_welcome:
    pattern:  /
    defaults:
      _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Welcome:index
      _template: AcmeDemoBundle:Welcome:index # added by me
```

this generates an error:

> FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getTemplate() on
>   a non-object in
>   .... \vendor\sensio\framework-extra-bundle\Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener.php
>   line 62

now, in TemplateListener, what we have is:

```
    if (!$configuration = $request->attributes->get('_template')) {
        return;
    }


    if (!$configuration->getTemplate()) {
        $guesser = $this->container->get('sensio_framework_extra.view.guesser');
        $configuration->setTemplate($guesser->guessTemplateName($controller, $request, $configuration->getEngine()));
    }
```

$configuration is a String, actually the template I put in routing.yml (AcmeDemoBundle:Welcome:index). Checked by adding a `var_dump` and also inspecting ParameterBag -> get method which is what `$request->attributes` is.

So. Why TemplateListener is expecting an object? What am I missing? Am I missconfiguring in routing.yml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This parameter is not available in Symfony itself.

Feature is provided by **SyliusResourceBundle** and available only in Sylius controllers.
And apparently `_template` request attribute conflicts with SensioFrameworkExtraBundle, which uses same name to store object.

We have to move those parameters one config node deeper, to avoid such problems in future.
You can keep an eye on the https://github.com/Sylius/SyliusResourceBundle repository, fix should arrive today.

Comment: great! thank you Pawel, I thought it was some symfony stuff (it looked like), otherwise I would have asked in github. regards